# Regex (PCRE) lookahead/behind include to match result

Tags: regex, pcre

What is the correct way to include lookahead/lookbehind into a match result?

```
some text <needed string> some other text
```

What if need to include `<>` into a match result?

This, of course, works fine:

```
<(?<=\<).+(?=\>)>
```

but it doesn't seem correct to me. Is there a better/more correct way to include lookahead/behind parameters into a match result?

Comment: At face value you can just do `<[^>]+>` but I feel like I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: What you're passing into lookahead/lookbehind is NOT included in a match result. My question is - what is a correct way to include what you've passed there?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why you need lookarounds to begin with. Why can't you just do e.g. `"some text <needed foo string> some other text"` => `<[^>]+foo[^>]+>` => `<needed foo string>` ?

Comment: but anyways, you didn't specify which language this is in, but in some languages, you can use capture groups inside lookahead/lookbehind to capture to a separate group

Comment: @CrayonViolent The "PCRE" specifies the flavour/implementation of regex; it's a library that's used in various languages and tools, but pretty much all the features will be the same no matter where it's used. It stands for "Perl Compatible Regular Expressions", but has diverged a little bit from the actual Perl implementation over the years.

Comment: @IMSoP I know that PCRE is the regex engine. But different languages (e.g. PHP) may have extra features built in to make use of or return certain things, making use of PCRE. PCRE is the engine. Other things like languages (e.g. php) or editors make use of it. My point was to that.

Comment: @IMSoP for example php `preg_match('~<(?<=(<)).+(?=(>))>~',$string,$match);` will pop `$match` with  `Array ( [0] => <needed string>   [1] => <    [2] => >)`  but this may not be the case for other languages.

Comment: @CrayonViolent The way the result is materialised may vary, but the syntax inside the regex is all provided by the library, AFAIK. So `(.)(.)(.)` will return three capture groups; in PHP, that will be an array of strings, and in another language it might be a special object, or a bunch of magic variables. It's possible that something has integrated PCRE and not exposed capture groups at all, but I don't think that's particularly relevant, since the question only asks about the syntax of the regex itself.

Comment: Note that this part `<(?<=\<)` matches `<` and asserts what is directly to the left is `<` which is just matched. This part `(?=\>)>` first asserts what is directly to the right is `>` and then matches `>`.

Comment: @IMSoP well it is relevant, because OP said they wanted it to be part of the matched result. In practice, nobody uses a regex engine by itself; they use it within the context of something else (e.g. language or editor). PCRE itself may return those groups but OP is almost certainly not working with the raw PCRE engine. So we cannot definitively say whether or not whatever context OP is working in will have those groups available. I simply didn't want to assume whatever context OP is working in would expose it.

Answer (score 2):

You are over-thinking it:

```
<.*?>
```

`.*?` means "as few chars as possible", and angle brackets carry no special meaning so do not need escaping.

Comment: He may be using `<` and `>` as pattern delimiter.

Comment: Indeed, but note that `(?<=\K<).*?>` is also possible (useless, but possible).

Answer (score 0):

So in regex there are a thousand ways to skin a cat. yours looks a little too well thought out.

Why cant it just be `\<.+?\>`?

Works here. https://regex101.com/r/GQ0O31/1/